# INSERT statement conflicted

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

This error is popular here but I have a different case here. I have the tables linked. I have data in the Department table, so the Foreign Key exists.

Here, is the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Department_Department_Id". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-hr_pcms-20181109102923", table "dbo.Department", column 'Department_Id'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 153:   {
>   Line 154:       var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
>   Line 155:       var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
>   Line 156:       if (result.Succeeded)
>   Line 157:       {

The main error is in line 155

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.Department_Department_Id". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-hr_pcms-20181109102923", table "dbo.Department", column 'Department_Id'.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2555674
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5958364
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +255
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader(Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +262
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal) +652
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +245
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +156
>          System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) +86
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +38
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext() +2714
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.d__0.MoveNext() +417

```
[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.<UpdateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +640
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext() +741
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext() +379
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() +346
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<SaveChangesInternalAsync>d__31.MoveNext() +799

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<SaveChanges>d__61.MoveNext() +214
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<CreateAsync>d__38.MoveNext() +243
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__73.MoveNext() +1050
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__79.MoveNext() +442
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   hr_pcms.Controllers.<Register>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\hr_pcms\hr_pcms\Controllers\AccountController.cs:155
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +152
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +125
```

With this application I used, selected the Individual Authentication. I never edit the AccountController, But I expanded the Model by adding columns to the AspNetUsers Table.

Any helpful suggestion would be great.

Comment: I think you are trying to use a "deparment_id" that does not exists.. Debug and see the value of department_id in your insert query and make sure it exists in dbo.Department table

Comment: There is data in the Department table. And i am sure i am using the id that exists.

Comment: If you are inserting data in Departments table, then the other table where Department_id is foreign key by using threads, make sure you are adding the data to the Department table (which is the parent one) first.

Comment: You insert a new ApplicationUser without any reference to Department so I bet its Department_Id is 0.

Comment: @GertArnold not 0 but null, i believe.

Comment: *I believe* - Don't. It's either 0 or null, figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the columns you added to the AspNetUsers table include the foreign key to Department_Department_Id.
The problem I believe is you are adding a user - but the addition code does not set that user's Department_Id - so in effect it is adding a null for the Department_Id and keys cannot be null.  To fix this - create a custom MyUser class derived from ApplicationUser including the Department_Id and any other columns relevant, and use that derived class to create the new user. Then assign the DepartmentId before calling Create.

I did this a while ago, might have to Google it as there are samples on how to add columns to the defined AspNet tables.  I believe I also updated the scripts the project uses to create the tables with the new columns defined in them so if run without a database, it creates a new one with correct configuration. From your text, you might already have done this...

Update - (I can only add here, need more rep before I can add or reply to comments).
Figured you could Google it - I did.
You did not comment on whether you just added columns to the AspNetUsers model - or created a derived class as I mentioned. Others answered the same thing I did - you cannot instantiate a new user without assigning a DepartmentId for them first - and can't do it first as you need the UserId to exist first - so it must be done at the same time, like I suggested.

Here are some links that add columns to AspNetUser correctly:

- [Ruard van Elburg's answer here to someone doing the same
  thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43814598) And in that post, the next answer has MS link to how to do
  it in VS2013.
- [Another post from MS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37797.asp-net-identity-customize-user-authentication.aspx) on one way to add fields to the
  authentication model.
- [An MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818488.aspx) specifically on storing user info in AS.NET
  Identity.

Look at these links and see how easy it is.  Here is a quick whip-up idea - not done in VS, sorry - untested. but just to give you a rough idea...
I do not have access to the project for which I did it last year, so can't provide quick accurate answers.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     // Because it is derived, all existing AspNetUser columns are inherited
     // just need to add your new columns
     public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

// model used for login page - with validation within page for items
public class LoginViewModel()
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DepartmentList {
       get {return new List<SelectListItem>() { 
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Department A", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Department B", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text = "Department C", Value = "3"}
         };
    }
    private int selectedDepartment { 
        return DepartmentList.SelectedValue != null ? 
               Convert.Int32(DepartmentList.SelectedValue) : -1;
    }
}
```

on your web page (you didn't say what you are using asp.net/mvc/other) - they must select which Department to login too, maybe a drop-down with values like

```
Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedItem, Model.DepartmentList)

// then something like
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel lmodel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(lmodel);
    }

    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser() {
        UserName = lmodel.username,
        Password = lmodel.password,
        //... other AspNetUser values assigned?
        //...,
        Department_Id = lmodel.selectedDepartment
    }
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded) {
       await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }        
}
```