# Getting error during to add some new fields into AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I just migrated from ASP.NET MVC to Blazor. I have created a new project that has authorization and authentication. When I want to add a series of new columns to the `AspNetUsers` table, I frequently encounter various errors.

> IdentityUser Issue - Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' this type is not included in the model for the context

and

> Unable to materialize entity instance of type 'Resource'. No discriminators matched the discriminator value ''."

and

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context

and

> The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined

My DbContext looks like this:

```
using LoginAndAuthProj.Server.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.ValueGeneration.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoginAndAuthProj.Server.MainDbContext
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEventUserLog>(entity =>
            {
                var pb = entity.Property(e => e.UId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                if (Database.IsInMemory())
                {
                    pb.HasValueGenerator<InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<decimal>>();
                }
            });

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<MyEventUserLog> MyEventUserLogs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the login controller:

```
using LoginAndAuthProj.Shared.DTOs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoginAndAuthProj.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserToken>> Login([FromBody] UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager
                .PasswordSignInAsync(userInfo.Email, userInfo.StrPassword, false, false);
            UserToken ut = new UserToken();

            // if(result.RequiresTwoFactor ==  )
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                ut = BuildToken(userInfo);
                ut.Responser.ResponsState = Shared.Enumes.ResponserState.Successful;
                ut.Responser.StrMessage = "Login OK . . .";

                return ut;
            }
            else
            {
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userInfo.Email);
                    var tokenMain = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, "Email");
                    ut.Responser.StrMessage = tokenMain.ToString();
                    ut.Responser.ResponsState = Shared.Enumes.ResponserState.TwoVerification;
                    Console.WriteLine(ut.Responser.StrMessage);

                    return ut;
                }
                else
                {
                    ut.Responser.ResponsState = Shared.Enumes.ResponserState.Fail;
                    ut.Responser.StrMessage = "Login OK . . .";
                    //return BadRequest("Login Failed");

                    return ut;
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("LoginTwoStep")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserToken>> LoginTwoStep([FromBody] UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                var appUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userInfo.Email);
                var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Email", userInfo.StrCode, false, userInfo.CanRememberMe);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return BuildToken(userInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    UserToken ut = new UserToken();
                    ut.Responser.ResponsState = Shared.Enumes.ResponserState.Fail;
                    ut.Responser.StrMessage = "Code is wrong . . . .";
                    return ut;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String Err = ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine(Err);
                UserToken ut = new UserToken();
                ut.Responser.ResponsState = Shared.Enumes.ResponserState.Fail;
                ut.Responser.StrMessage = "Code is wrong . . . ." + Err;
                return ut;
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("Create")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserToken>> CreateUser([FromBody] UserInfo model)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = "00000011110000", 
            EmailConfirmed = true, PhoneNumberConfirmed = true, TwoFactorEnabled = false, LockoutEnabled = false, AccessFailedCount = 0};

            try
            {
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.StrPassword);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return BuildToken(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Username Or Password is invalid");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private UserToken BuildToken(UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Email),
                new Claim("MyClaim", "My Claim Value")
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["jwt:key"]));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

            JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: null,
                audience: null,
                claims: claims,
                expires: expireDate,
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

            return new UserToken
            {
                Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                ExpireDate = expireDate
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Startup file in Server Layer

```
using LoginAndAuthProj.Server.MainDbContext;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using System;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using LoginAndAuthProj.Shared.DTOs;

namespace LoginAndAuthProj.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["jwt:key"])),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                });
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add just this three fields to that table

```
public String UsersAddress { get; set; }
public int CityID { get; set; }
public Byte[] PictureOfUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: And where do you write those properties? In which class? Is a class derived from IdentityUser?

Comment: I hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810032/add-column-to-aspnetusers-table) can help you!

Comment: I chose not to mess with the default Identity / Membership scaffolding at all.  Instead, I added a separate table, `ExtendedUserInfo`.    My rationale was this-- what happens the next time MS updates all that stuff in .net 7 or 8, and I can't use new features with the existing tables?  I've already gone through that with WebForms, and I'd rather not fight with auto-generated content in the future.

Comment: If they really decide to make this architecture incompatible to some unknown future evolutions of their library, a lot of people will be in trouble because this approach (deriving from IdentityUser) is exactly what they recommend to do. Anyway, if you want to stick to the bare bone Identity infrastructure then you are on your own if you want to extend the IdentityUser. You need to provide everything needed to read and write to your custom table and keep it linked to AspNetUsers in a one-to-one relationship using the Id field.

Comment: It was very well explained. @Mohsen Yaghoubi  I did not understand much. It was very technically explained. Since I have just entered Blazer, I did not understand much.

Comment: I wrote in `ApplicationUser` Class @Steve and inside of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this video from [youtube website](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYT9ykDEnjE)! at first you shoud create a class and add you fields into that class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [MaxLength(1500, ErrorMessage = "The Error Message")]
        public String UsersAddress { get; set; }
        public int? CityID { get; set; }
        public Byte[]? PictureOfUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Then change `ApplicationDbContext` to `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` something like below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEventUserLog>(entity =>
            {
                var pb = entity.Property(e => e.UId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                if (Database.IsInMemory())
                {
                    pb.HasValueGenerator<InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<decimal>>();
                }
            });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<MyEventUserLog> MyEventUserLogs { get; set; }
    }
```

After that in Startup file chanage this part

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

to

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and inside of **login controller** replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser` then use `Enable-migration` after that `add-migration WithName` finally `Update-Databse` and run the project.

Comment: Let me to check and answer you.  and another question.  Is there a need to create a `DbSet` or not?

Comment: Dear @pufivina No, there is no need to create a DbSet. Because you are not creating a new table in the database.

Comment: and another point. add before `public Byte[]? PictureOfUser { get; set;  }` size limiter as  `[MaxLength(250)]` If you do not use the size limiter, the default value or the maximum is considered.